# Bootstrap v4 offsets within sass/scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

How do i use offsets within my own sass file using bootstrap v4?

I was using: `@extend .col-sm-offset-2;`

After i updated bootstrap v4 from the git, it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/), it would work like this :

```
@include make-col-offset(2)
```

I suppose it will be sm if the column is small already